# Enabling / Disabling all ASP Controls in Table / Placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, placeholder

How do I disable for example all button controls in a certain placeholder?

The plot: I am coding an application for web that uses some buttons which get disabled after you click them.

Now when I click the "New Game" button, all previously disabled buttons should be enabled again.

Comment: Please check out these articles : http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=3592 http://geekswithblogs.net/jwhitehorn/archive/2006/06/17/82214.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in in a [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. Disabling the panel will disable all its sub controls.